# How to retain line breaker after converting blob to PDF

Tags: apex

I have a requirement where we are capturing inbound emails through email services and strong  the information in custom object and they want email body to be converted as PDF and stored in attachment object for above custom object.

Problem:

When I am converting attachment blob to PDF line brakes are not retained in PDF.

How can I retain line brakes after converting to PDF?

I have used `\n` and `br` tags but no luck.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please make sure to include the relevant portions of your code, along with the specific issue you are struggling with and the complete text and location of any errors, in the body of your question. See [ask] for more about our expectations, and please [edit] your question to add information rather than posting comments.